# Sending Subversion Change Log Info Via Hudson

Tags: svn, hudson

I'm trying to integrate Hudson into our development process, and everything is going smooth except for one thing.

I had been using Phing to do deployments, and one of the things that was being triggered was an email to our tech support email address containing a list of all the commit messages between the last time code was deployed and the present SVN revision.  I was doing something like this:

- read in a file from the root directory of the currently-deployed application that contains the SVN revision when the app was deployed
- place that value in a Phing variable
- insert that value into a command to send the SVN commit messages via email
- create a file in the root directory of the newly-deployed application that contains the current SVN revision

I'd like to be able to add that information to the email that gets sent out by Hudson when a successful build goes out.  Any pointers on how to accomplish this task in Hudson would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This annoyed me, too, when I switched from CruiseControl to Hudson.  You can do what you need by using the [Hudson email-ext plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Email-ext+plugin) - after you install the plugin, you'll see an option "Editable email configuration" at the end of each job configuration page.  Click on the help links to see what information you can include in your emails; the ${CHANGES} token is the one you need to shoe the SVN commits that triggered the build.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  However, I'm wondering how it would work if we want to stack up several commits before deploying as that is sort of how we work.  We're working on the test stuff too, but baby steps.

Comment: email-ext does handle that.  It'll collect the commit messages into a list in the email (gareth means ${CHANGES}).

Answer (score 2):

If the [Hudson email-ext plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Email-ext+plugin) is not enough have a look at the two following pages for a patch of the plugin. This patch allows the use of groovy scripts.

http://techkriti.wordpress.com/2008/08/30/using-groovy-with-hudson-to-send-rich-text-email/#postcomment

http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-2175