# How to make Hudson create changelog since last deploy

Tags: hudson, changelog

I would like our Hudson deploy job to output a changelog of all Subversion changes since last deploy. Any ideas to how that is done?

Comment: Please give us a little more info about what constitutes a deploy? Are you running a specific Hudson job to do a deploy? - If so you can get the date of the last deploy from the build folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Hudson automatically generates a list of changes since last build.

And since we set up deployment in Hudson, each deployment has a list of commits along with their changes. The [Hudson email-ext plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Email-ext+plugin) makes them available as `$CHANGES`, so that it for instance can send an email with `$CHANGES` in the email body.

Of course, there are limits to this approach: Only changes since last deploy are here. So if you manually stop deployment, or the deployment build breaks, then the next changelog only contains changes since that. And not since last successful deployment.

Also see a related discussion in the Stackoverflow question [Sending Subversion Change Log Info Via Hudson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916105/sending-subversion-change-log-info-via-hudson)

Answer (score 0):

Add a build step in your hudson job that runs a shell script:

```
svn log -r HEAD:PREV > ./changelog
```

To generate a change list of the changes since the last commit.

You can also do a log -r by date/date-range.

Can you determine your last deploy (I assume you may not deploy with every build.) Some more information about your process will help.

If you tag your deployments with a normalised pattern it would be fairly simple to create a counter that would allow you to get the right SVN revision.

Comment: This is not "since last deploy".

Comment: We don't have enough info to determine when the job is a deploy.